# Returning a value from a content script

Tags: google-chrome-extension

When executing a content script from a popup is there a way for that content script to return a value to the popup where the script was executed.

Comment: Read Google's Extension docs on [message passing](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html#simple). Instead of responding in popup.html, do nothing, just receive your request. The request you received could be anything, like the value you want it to return to the popup file.
But I think you're already using message passing, since you say you're executing the content script from the popup. If that's what you're doing, then you should be able to return the value in the response.

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to just have the content script return a value rather than having it send a value and catch it with the popup.

Comment: When you say, 'When executing a content script from a popup,' do you mean you're sending a request to the content script (from the popup) to execute a function?

Comment: I'm making this call in the popup `chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "content_script.js" });`

Comment: Well, then there's no way to do what you want without sending a request from the script.

Comment: Right now I have it set up where the `chrome.extension.sendRequest` in the content script sends the data to the `chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener` in popup.  I was hoping to do this in a more readable way since the `.sendRequest` is not really a request because its simply sending data and does not a expect a response.

Answer (score 2):

Referring to Google's [Docs](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html#simple), use the following code:

## contentscript.js

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({value: "hello"}, null);
```

## popup.html

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function myFunc(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        doStuffWithValue(request.value);
        chrome.runtime.onMessage.removeListener(myFunc); //if you want to stop listening after receiving the message
    });
```

Comment: This is how I have it set up now, I'm looking for something more readable because the `.sendRequest`is not really a request seeing as it doesn't expect a response.

Comment: You can just put it in a function like function sendValue(value){chrome.extension.sendRequest({"value": value},null)} and then use the sendValue function. Might make it easier on you to remember and understand it.

Comment: That's a pretty nice solution.  Probably not worth it unless there is a bunch of requests.